# Lock screen and time

Tags: windows-7, login-screen, lock

When locking a session on Win7 using Ctr Alt + Del, the following screen appears.

[image]

This image is of the pre-login screen, however this is the screen I wold like it displayed on.

Is it possible to show a custom message somewhere on this screen like;

> "This PC has been locked for x minutes"

Would I need to write a custom script for such a feature? If so, any direction or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Note: the provided screen shot is of the pre-logon screen, not the lock screen.

Comment: thanks @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I suppose I'd like it on this screen as well then! I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a working solution for you right now, but there is a way to [change a logon background image](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/coolstuff/Customize-Your-Logon-Background-in-Windows-7).

So one could write a script, that would create such image with date\time, and run this script via Task Scheduler every one minute or so if PC is not idle. If Windows doesn't cache this image, there is a chance, that it will work.

This could help you to create image:

- [Add text on image at specific point using imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236898/add-text-on-image-at-specific-point-using-imagemagick)
- [Can I “draw”/create an image with a given text with powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067920/can-i-draw-create-an-image-with-a-given-text-with-powershell)

P.S. You may also be interested in this: [Adding messages to Windows 7's logon screen](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/adding-messages-to-windows-7s-logon-screen/)